# How to have search functionality in android using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I developed an application which contains a large list of different users with their name and id. Now I want to perform a search functionality so that I can search for a particular user using their name or id.

Can anyone help me in achieving this using Phonegap?

*Details:*

I am getting the list of usernames from json webservice call and I want to perform search operation for those.

For example I have android tablet application which contains 3 list views with almost 40 different user names and on the top of that page I have a search bar. In that search bar if I enter a username or id it should search for the entered data and direct me to there.

Comment: i think you need to add more info like on which data you need to perform search: stored data or memory list

Comment: @dhaval hi i added some explination i hope it's clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put a listview example in following fiddle and use the filtertext attribute to search on multiple data. See if this fits in your solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/HZg5J/

### Edit

The fiddle now also includes the filter callback option provided by the jQuery Mobile to customize the response.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, in the link you've sent it's only working for four and if i enter one or two or three it's not displaying anything i am not able to get it. can u please help me? @dhaval

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to include one ore way to filter and fix the search data

Comment: the fiddle already has the full source code. You will see the included js/css files on the left.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12195/discussion-between-androidfresher-and-dhaval)

Comment: hi can u tell me what does this line mean
<li data-filtertext="11:first:one">

Comment: this is the text on which search keyword will work, by default the filter works on the text of the list but if you define `data-filtertext` then it will filter the list based on the attribute's content